# Add PHP functionality to Docker Compose Python/Flask Container

Tags: python, php, docker, flask, docker-compose

I have a Flask-based webapp built in Docker Compose using Gunicorn, Redis, Celery and Postgres. The app needs to call a 3rd-party math function that is written in PHP and will be hosted within the app structure as a PHP file. It's not possible to rewrite this function in Python unfortunately. I need therefore to get PHP running inside my main webapp container so I can access the file. I have the relevant subprocess code ready but am struggling with how to get PHP running within the relevant container. The important files are as follows:

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'
 services:
   postgres:
     image: 'postgres:9.5'
     restart: always
     env_file:
       - '.env'
     volumes:
       - 'postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data'
     ports:
       - '5432:5432'

   redis:
     image: 'redis:3.0-alpine'
     command: redis-server --requirepass devpassword
     volumes:
       - 'redis:/var/lib/redis/data'
     ports:
       - '6379:6379'

   web:
     image: my_app_web:rv19
     build: .
     restart: always
     command: >
       gunicorn -c "python:config.gunicorn" --reload --timeout 5 "my_app.app:create_app()"
     env_file:
       - '.env'
     volumes:
       - '.:/my_app'
     ports:
       - '8000:8000'
     depends_on:
       - postgres
     links:
       - redis
       - celery

   celery:
     build: .
     command: celery worker -B -l info -A my_app.blueprints.contact.tasks
     env_file:
       - '.env'
     volumes:
       - '.:/my_app'
     links:
       - redis
     depends_on:
       - redis

 volumes:
   postgres:
   redis:
```

And the Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7-slim
MAINTAINER AAAAA AAAAA <aaaa@aaaa.a>

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -qq -y \
  build-essential libpq-dev --no-install-recommends

ENV INSTALL_PATH /my_app
RUN mkdir -p $INSTALL_PATH

WORKDIR $INSTALL_PATH

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .
RUN pip install --editable .

CMD gunicorn -c "python:config.gunicorn" "my_app.app:create_app()"
```

.env file:

```
COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=my_app

POSTGRES_USER=my_app
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=devpassword

PYTHONUNBUFFERED=true
```

Checking for availability of PHP within the app:

```
php = os.system('php --version')
print(php)
```

returns:

```
php: not found
web_1       | 32512
```

Can anybody please advise on how I can get PHP running alongside Python within my main web container so that I can call the function from my Python code?

Comment: Would it not be better to make some kind of API instead of running them together?

Comment: In order to run more than one service in a container look at [SupervisorD](http://supervisord.org/) https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/

Comment: Could you please check this page - https://hub.docker.com/_/php

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to serve php file and only execute it via cli, just install php in the container. You can do that in your Dockerfile by adding **php** in **apt-get** command:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -qq -y \
  build-essential libpq-dev php --no-install-recommends
```